# $A = \{{1, ... , n\}}$ - How many $(B,C) \in P(A) \times P(A)$ are there such that $B \cap \overline{C} = \emptyset$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

$A = \{{1, ... , n\}}$
How many $(B,C) \in  P(A) \times P(A)$ are there such that $B \cap \overline{C} = \emptyset$ ?
I got to the conclusion that it must be $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}2^k$ because for each size of $C$ I'm looking for the size of all its subsets because each subset will be suitable to be $B$.
Is it correct and is there another way to calculate it without a sigma?

Comment: If you are the same Lisa who has posting other combinatorics problems on this site, you should [merge](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) your accounts since you will earn more [reputation](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) on this site and the [privileges](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) that accrue with your reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conclusion that $B$ is a subset of set $C$ is correct.  For each subset $C$ of size $k$, there are $2^k$ subsets.  However, you forgot to take into account that there are $\binom{n}{k}$ subsets of size $k$ in set $A$.  Hence, the number of order pairs $(B, C) \in \mathcal{P}(A) \times \mathcal{P}(A)$ such that $B \cap \overline{C} = \emptyset$ is 
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}2^k = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}2^k1^{n - k} = (2 + 1)^n = 3^n$$
by the Binomial Theorem.

**Alternate Solution:**  Observe that each of the $n$ elements in $A$ is in $B$, $C \backslash B$, or $\overline{C}$.  Thus, there are $3^n$ ordered pairs $(B, C) \in \mathcal{P}(A) \times \mathcal{P}(A)$ such that $B \cap \overline{C} = \emptyset$.

Comment: Thanks (: That's amazing! By $C - B$ you mean $C$ \ $B$ ?

Comment: That is what I meant by $C - B$, but I changed the notation to conform to the form you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

The condition $B \cap \overline{C} = \emptyset$ tells you that $B$ must be a subset of $C$. So consider all possible sets $C$, and for each $C$ consider all of its possible subsets.

You'll get a more complicated sum as follows: $\Sigma_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} 2^k$.